# Get last Monday with WeekdayName function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to capture previous Monday date. So, if today is 6/5/2017, then if I open excel I need to return 1/5/2017 (last Monday) using VBA.

This is my code:

```
Dim strdate As String
Select Case WeekdayName(Now())
Case vbMonday
  strdate = Now()
Case vbTuesday
  strdate = Now() - 1
Case vbWednesday
  strdate = Now() - 2
Case vbThursday
  strdate = Now() - 3
Case vbFriday
  strdate = Now() - 4
Case vbSaturday
  strdate = Now() - 5
Case vbSunday
  strdate = Now() - 6
End Select
```

Can anyone suggest why this does not return the expected result?

Comment: Try WeekDay() instead of WeekDayName()

Answer (score 4):

The previous Monday's date is always

```
PreviousMonday = Date - Weekday(Date - 1, vbMonday)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Dim d As Date
    d = Date

Do Until Weekday(d) = vbMonday
    d = DateAdd("y", -1, d)
Loop

'd = date of previous Monday
```